# Django user in tornado

Tags: python, django, websocket, tornado, sockjs

I have been using the code below to get the django user in tornado:

```
from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.auth
import django.utils.importlib

import tornado
from tornado.options import options
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import sockjs.tornado

class RouterConnection(sockjs.tornado.SockJSConnection):

    def get_current_user(self, info):
        engine = django.utils.importlib.import_module(django.conf.settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        session_key = str(info.get_cookie(django.conf.settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)).split('=')[1]

        class Dummy(object):
            pass

        django_request = Dummy()
        django_request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
        user = django.contrib.auth.get_user(django_request)
        return user


    def on_open(self, info):
        user = self.get_current_user(info=info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging
    Router = sockjs.tornado.SockJSRouter(RouterConnection)

    app = tornado.web.Application(Router.urls, debug=True, )

    app.listen(settings.TORNADO_PORT)

    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

My problem is as follows:
Django changes logging configuration and I can no longer see any log output from tornado. How can I reinitialize tornado logging? Is there other way to integrate Django with Tornado?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To reset the django logging i use the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('')
for handler in logger.handlers:
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

When using the django.conf module the LazySettings class is initialized where initialized django logger.
Also I had to rewrite the code with using initialized settings class:

```
from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.auth
import django.utils.importlib

import tornado
from tornado.options import options
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import sockjs.tornado

TORNADO_PORT = settings.TORNADO_PORT

class RouterConnection(sockjs.tornado.SockJSConnection):

    def get_current_user(self, info):
        engine = django.utils.importlib.import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        session_key = str(info.get_cookie(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)).split('=')[1]

        class Dummy(object):
            pass

        django_request = Dummy()
        django_request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
        user = django.contrib.auth.get_user(django_request)
        return user


    def on_open(self, info):
        user = self.get_current_user(info=info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('')
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        logger.removeHandler(handler)
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    Router = sockjs.tornado.SockJSRouter(RouterConnection)

    app = tornado.web.Application(Router.urls, debug=settings.DEBUG)

    app.listen(settings.TORNADO_PORT)

    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer` to wrap Django. Refer to [this demo project](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you Stefano, it's a good practice to integrate django with tornado, but it does not give an access to the django user.

Comment: This does not give access to the Django user :[